# imprimir Treemap según los mayores valores

Tags: java

Estoy leyendo palabras de un fichero y guardándolas en un Treemap, para contar qué palabras son las más repetidas, de forma que incremento el valor si la palabra ya está en el map. Pero, ¿como podría imprimir las 50 palabras más repetidas? Es decir, serían las que tuvieran un valor más grande.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("fichero.txt"));
    TreeMap<String,Integer> mymap = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();

    while(input.hasNext()){

        String palabra = input.next();
        if(mymap.containsKey(palabra)){

           mymap.put(palabra,mymap.get(palabra)+1);
        }
        else{

           mymap.put(palabra,1);
        }


    }
```

De esta forma, al terminar de leer el fichero, tendría un TreeMap:
Hola 20
que 10
la 3
que 7
los 4
como 3
.
.
.

Y lo que quiero hacer es imprimir las 10 palabras (por ejemplo) más repetidas.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Código por favor. Has escuchado *Una imagen vale mas que mil palabras*. Unas cuantas lineas de código también.

Comment: Acabo de editar. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas Java 8, será muy fácil hacerlo con [`stream`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/procesamiento-streams-java-se-8-2763402-esa.html). Imaginemos que tienes este `TreeMap`:

```
    TreeMap<String, Integer> myMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        myMap.put("Hola", 50);
        myMap.put("zz", 250);
        myMap.put("a", 1);
        myMap.put("bbb", 13);
        myMap.put("cc", 50);
        myMap.put("yui", 3);
        myMap.put("rtys", 4);
        myMap.put("OMG", 2);
        myMap.put("Un millón", 1000000);
        myMap.put("Cero", 0);
        myMap.put("Ok", 1);
        myMap.put("t", 50);
        myMap.put("ffff", 18950);
```

Podemos usar `stream` para ordenarlo en orden de mayor a menor usando los valores, y decirle que nos imprima únicamente `10` valores usando `limit`.

```
    myMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry. <String, Integer> comparingByValue().reversed())
            .limit(10)
            .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

#### Resultado:

```
Un millón=1000000
ffff=18950
zz=250
Hola=50
cc=50
t=50
bbb=13
rtys=4
yui=3
OMG=2
```

Tú puedes usar `e`, para obtener las claves y valores por separado si lo deseas. Por ejemplo:

```
    myMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry. <String, Integer> comparingByValue().reversed())
            .limit(10)
            .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println("Key: "+e.getKey()+ " Value: "+e.getValue()));
```

#### Resultado:

```
Key: Un millón Value: 1000000
Key: ffff Value: 18950
Key: zz Value: 250
Key: Hola Value: 50
Key: cc Value: 50
Key: t Value: 50
Key: bbb Value: 13
Key: rtys Value: 4
Key: yui Value: 3
Key: OMG Value: 2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Funciona perfectamente. ¿Y si por ejemplo quisiera imprimir las palabras repetidas más de X veces? ¿Existe algún método de Stream() para ello? Gracias de nuevo @A. Cedano